# Two lines in a bracket

Tags: equations, brackets

I am facing trouble trying to enter the formula:

[image]

I entered:

```
\Bigg[ \vec{p}^T_1+\vec{p}^T_2=\vec{E}^{miss}_T, p^2_1=0, (p_1+p_l)^2=p^2_2=M^2_W, (p_1+p_l+p_{b_1})^2=(p_2+p{b_2})^2=m^2_y \Bigg]
```

but the brackets do not cover the lines together. Could you help me in this issue?

Edit: It is now solved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want `\[\Bigg[\begin{aligned} \vec{p}^T_1+\vec{p}^T_2=\vec{E}^{miss}_T, p^2_1=0, (p_1+p_l)^2=p^2_2=M^2_W,\\(p_1+p_l+p_{b_1})^2=(p_2+p{b_2})^2=m^2_y \end{aligned}\Bigg]\]`? Please provide a compilable but minimal example of  what you have!

Answer (score 4):

I'd use (or perhaps, abuse) `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\,
  \vec{p}^{\,T}_1+\vec{p}^{\,T}_2=\vec{E}^{\,\textnormal{miss}}_T,\;
  p^2_1=0,\;
  (p_1+p_l)^2=p^2_2=M^2_W,
\\[2\jot]
\hfill (p_1+p_l+p_{b_1})^2=(p_2+p{b_2})^2=m^2_y
\,
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\,` in the exponent of `\vec` objects, to avoid the arrow clashing in the exponent itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `amsmath` package then you can use an `aligned` environment for the inner material.  You need to mark some alignment point on each line with `&`, from your example I have put that at the right-hand end.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \Bigg[\ 
  \begin{aligned}
    \vec{p}^T_1 + \vec{p}^T_2 = \vec{E}^{\mathrm{miss}}_T,\ 
    p^2_1 = 0,\ 
    (p_1+p_l)^2 = p^2_2 = M^2_W,&\\
    (p_1+p_l+p_{b_1})^2 = (p_2+p{b_2})^2 = m^2_y&
  \end{aligned}
  \ 
  \Bigg]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

An interesting alternative is the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`.  This sets the first line aligned and the final line right aligned without requiring marking of any alignment points, but does this with a slight offset:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \Bigg[\ 
  \begin{multlined}
    \vec{p}^T_1 + \vec{p}^T_2 = \vec{E}^{\mathrm{miss}}_T,\ 
    p^2_1 = 0,\ 
    (p_1+p_l)^2 = p^2_2 = M^2_W,\\
    (p_1+p_l+p_{b_1})^2 = (p_2+p{b_2})^2 = m^2_y
  \end{multlined}
  \ 
  \Bigg]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That isn't really related to `mathtools`, other than the fact that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`.

Comment: @daleif True.  Updated showing `multlined` too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses "just" an `array` environment surrounded by `\left[` and `\right]`. (The idea for the extra spacing before the superscript `T`'s comes from egreg's solution.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
\vec{p}^{\,T}_1+\vec{p}^{\,T}_2=\vec{E}^{\,\textup{miss}}_T,\ 
  p^2_1=0,\ 
  (p_1+p_\ell)^2=p^2_2=M^2_W, \\[1ex]
(p_1+p_\ell+p_{b_1})^2=(p_2+p_{b_2})^2=m^2_y
\end{array} \right]
\]

\end{document}
```